# What are practical applications of Laplace Transforms in the real world

Tags: laplace-transform

In lay man's terms what really in the real world are practical examples of how Laplace transforms are used to solve basic mathematical problems in mechanical engineering I would really appreciate a very simple and clear answer with less mathematical jargon plus a few examples.

Comment: Check out [this page](https://www.intmath.com/laplace-transformation/10-applications.php). Note that I found this by searching "Laplace transform applications" -- you would benefit from doing some independent research first.

Comment: Finance: https://www.risklatte.xyz/Articles/QuantitativeFinance/QF184.php http://www.tsijournals.com/articles/laplace-transform-in-finance.pdf

Comment: [Basically, a Laplace transform will convert a function in some domain into a function in another domain, without changing the value of the function. (more in this quora answer on engineering to a quora question on computer science)](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-real-world-applications-of-Laplace-transform-especially-in-computer-science)

Comment: A *Laplacian* is something else. It is a differential operator. It is the *divergence* of the *gradient* : $\nabla \cdot (\nabla(\cdot))$.

Comment: It is apparently a very useful source for exercises for mechanical engineering students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were an electrical engineer the practical (and very useful) applications of the Laplace (Fourier) transform would be very clear.
That is, in crude words as you require,  the study of the response of a system to solicitations of different frequencies and how to cope with them.

The [Bode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) and Nyquist plots are paradigmatic.

In the mechanical field that finds application in the study of vibrations especially, which means resonance phenomena, acoustic noise, fatigue and so on.